# how can I merge columns from 2 tables with different number of rows using SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables, 'tab1' and 'tab2':

tab1 is:

```
col1
25.0
30.0
31.0
25.0
```

tab2 is:

```
col1    col2
25.0    11.0
30.0    99.0
31.0    57.0
```

I want to get the following merged table result by matching the col1 values in tab1 with col1 in tab2 (thus filling in using col2 values from tab2):

```
col1    col2
25.0    11.0
30.0    99.0
31.0    57.0
25.0    11.0
```

I am using this sqlite code currently:

```
INSERT INTO `merged_table1` 
SELECT * FROM tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2
ON tab1.col1 = tab2.col1;
```

However, the result is not correct (giving an extra column):

```
25  25  11
30  30  99
31  31  57
25  25  11
```

Comment: I believe I got it:`INSERT INTO `merged_table1` 
SELECT tab1.col1, tab2.col2
FROM tab1 
LEFT JOIN tab2
ON tab1.col1= tab2.col1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns actually have the same name, you can do the join using the USING clause, which automatically removes the duplicate column:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT *
FROM      tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 USING (col1);
```

Otherwise, just tell the database which columns you want:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT tab1.col1,
       tab2.col2
FROM      tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.col1 = tab2.col1;
```